# PayPal IPN: how to respond with invalid notification

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

After many readings I in the end integrated PayPal with the IPN method.
I perform 3 checks in `listener.php` which are:

1. check if the `txn_id` is not already in the db (someone can use an old confirmed transaction id to return a confirmed status, as far as it's written in the PayPal documentation)
2. check if `receiver_email` matches with the seller email
3. check if `custom` matches with the order id
4. check if `mc_gross` matches with the price

If all the checks gone right I insert all the data into the db; what I'm missing now is what should I do if any of those parameters doesn't match. Can I send back to PayPal a code message that means "hey PayPal, something gone wrong: delete the transaction, display an error message and eventually let the buyer try again"? If not, how would you handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. PayPal does not keep the user waiting during the IPN process, so the user is not there anymore to read errors or retries.

The appropriate action is probably a refund. I would trigger a notification to the store manager that they received an unjustified payment and leave it to a human to deal with the issue. 
It is an edge case that is more than rare if everything is well configured.

You did not mention calling PayPal to check for the authenticity of the call. You really should do that one first.

Comment: Do you mean opening a socket connection to PayPal like `$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);`? My question came from the draw in the [PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/) at the bottom of the page; point 3 says: `Your server must then validate the notification to ensure that it is legitimate`. What this sentence means then if not "your server must validate the notification aka the transaction"? Thanks!

Comment: It means that the first thing you need to do is to make an http call to PayPal (server to server) that contains all of the data you just received. PayPal will answer either "VERIFIED" or "INVALID" (or something like that).
The idea is that you are asking to PayPal: "I got this notification of payment; did you send it or is it a fake?"